# GCP SDK Authentication using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform

I wrote a simple code in Python using the googleapiclient library that just list my compute instances. I did not setup any authentication code, but instead, first time it ran it asked me to approve/consent/grant access and it used my already initialized and stored SDK credentials, the one I use in gcloud CLI.

I am trying to achieve the same goal but in a .NET app, using the Google.Cloud.Compute.V1 library from nuget, but I cant get to use my SDK credentials, how is that done?

I do not want to create an API key for my application, as this will no be distributed, its just a internal/test project. I need my .net code to use the authentication stored on my computer SDK

Please apologize for the explanation, I am just getting started with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you observed with your code using the Google Python SDK is implemented by [Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically).

There's another mechanism by which the credentials are discovered (which isn't covered in the ADC documentation) that's when [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) is used and when `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is not used (and is thus unset) too.

This is likely the behavior you observed with the Python code. You'd `gcloud auth application-default login` and not set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

This behavior should be consistent across SDKs **but** using `gcloud auth application-default login` is increasingly discouraged. It (possibly why it's not covered by the ADC documentation):

- (as you experience) can work "miraculously"
- the credentials are often too broad matching your user account's

On Linux, `gcloud application-default login` creates `${HOME}/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` and this is the key that's used by the SDK.

I encourage you to create a Service Account to function as the identity for your code and to grant this the minimal set of IAM roles/permissions that your code needs.

When your code runs on a Google compute service (e.g. Compute Engine, Cloud Run, Kubernetes Engine...), the credentials are obtained automatically using Metadata service.

When your code runs off-GCP (e.g. locally), you can create a Service Account key and `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json` and SDK-based code will use these automatically.

> **NOTE** For completeness, creating Service Account  **keys** is also discouraged. Keys are secrets and should be treated judiciously. A recent, powerful mechanism that provides access to GCP resources for code running off-GCP is to use [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain, that does make more sense now.
I was able to authenticate loading the application_default_credentials.json , although in Windows it doesn't seem to find that file right out the bath, but anyways I got what I need.

For this case it doesn't make any sense to create a serviceAccount. I understand the risks and the ugliness of this method but i just need to query a bunch of services to get list of resources, its just a one time task.

Comment: You're welcome! It's not "ugly" to do it that way. Just continue to be mindful of the risks with keys and be diligent about not checking keys into repos.